# Validate Email with HTML5

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using `bootstrap 3.3.7`, `jQuery 3.1.1` and `jQuery-UI 1.12.0` for a form to ask for email and some other details.

For using `autocomplete` I am using the example shows under

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Email looks like this

```
<div class='form-group row'>
  <label class='col-md-2 control-label'>To....</label>
  <div class='col-md-6'>
    <input type='email' class='form-control inputMail' name='mailTo' required multiple>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, input is type `email` and I would like to validate the input.

My problem is the last comma, this input will not be accepted.

Invalid input:

[image: invalid input]

But when I remove the last comma by hand it works.

Valid input:

[image: valid input]

Have anyone a solution how it works without removing the last comma by hand?

Comment: Could you not do something on select that would trim the last comma: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript chop/slice/trim off last character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952924/javascript-chop-slice-trim-off-last-character-in-string), and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369056/remove-comma-to-the-last-values-autocomplete-multiple-select

Comment: If trimming is not an option you can use your own pattern for the validation by setting the pattern attribute with your own regex.

Comment: I know that slice() is a possibility. But I think an own regex will be the best. Thank you